# My villager his trade is not locked but I can't do the trade

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I have a Librarian Villager and the first trade is the mending book and the second one is the bookshelf. Its not only this one but also the other villagers. The problem i when I give him emeralds he always gives me the bookshelf trade. Even when I press on the book trade it stays stuck on the bookshelf trade. I tried leveling him up one level. And I am able to do all the trade. Only the book trade seems to be stuck. (He is not sold out)

Comment: We’ll need some more information to reduce your problem. Could you post a screenshot of the villager interface? This will better help us find your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Look closer on the 'price' side of the enchanted book trade. There's a certain amount of emeralds - and a regular book. You have two slots for the 'paid' items. Put the emeralds in the first one and a plain unenchanted book in the other. Emeralds alone aren't enough for these trades.

Plain unenchanted books can be obtained in these ways:

- crafting 3 paper and 1 leather,
- breaking a bookshelf with a non-silktouch tool (you get 3 books)
- disenchanting an unwanted enchanted book in the grindstone